# Usar tabla creada phpmyadmin en Laravel

Tags: laravel

Tengo una tabla con mas de mil registros, que en su dia importe al phpmyadmin, con la cual no hice migracion de dicha tabla. Hice su respectivo modelo respetando los singulares y plurales correspondientes.
Decir que en "`local`" la tabla funciona perfectamente, pero el problema viene cuando esta en un servidor remoto cuando ejecuto una consulta en dicha tabla, me da este error.

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'rwebstu2_bpm_aplicacion4.V9prices' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `V9prices` where `referencia` = 10200.RF.W-AQ.MP)
```

Alguna sugerencia he buscado pero no he encontrado nada al respecto.

saludos.

Comment: Ya verificaste que los datos de conexión estén correctos y que la base de datos este completa?

Comment: Si los revise muchas veces y estan correctos.

Comment: no se si ayude pero prueba haciéndole un `composer dump-autoload` a tu proyecto porque es que lo que se entiende por el mensaje es que esa tabla no existe pero tu me dices que si esta.

Comment: Algo mas que probaría seria quitarle el `where` a ver si me sigue marcando el mismo error.

Comment: ok gracias, lo probare y comentare

Comment: Podrías mostrar la tabla y la consulta? gracias.

Comment: ¿puedes mostrar donde haces esa consulta? al igual que el modelo que estas usando para acceder a dicha tabla, lo mas seguro que no estas referenciando el modelo con el nombre de la tabla es decir poner algo como esto en tu Modelo `protected $table = "V9prices";`

Comment: @LuisVe seguramente algo no esta bien en el modelo, ¿puedes mostrarlo como lo tienes y si puedes tambien la estructura de la tabla para que podamos revisar?

Answer (score 0):

Crea un modelo con algún nombre legible y sobre escribe la variable table asignando el nombre de dicha tabla.

```
protected $table = 'nombreDeLaTabla';
```

Ejemplo de la documentación:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Flight extends Model
{
    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'my_flights';
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a todos, al final di con el fallo, no se porque en local me funcionaba y en el servidor no.
Al grano, el nombre de la tabla estaba escrito así "v9prices", el modelo y las llamadas para realizar dicha consulta estaban con, "V9price" modelo y"V9prices" las consultas respectivamente.
En local funcionaban perfectamente no daba ningún tipo de error, pero en el servidor remoto si. Hasta que cansado estuve mirando un rato desesperado la pantalla de error y me dije "Ahí esta el fallo".

Lo que todavía me pregunto es porque en local funcionaba y en remoto no.

Gracias a todos sois muy amables!!